# Naming dto objects

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, dto

I have a model object called `Country`:

```
class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Region[] Regions {get;set;}
    public URI[] Uris {get;set;}
}
```

and via WebService I want get this Country in few versions:

1. only Name and Code
2. every field
3. every filed without Uris
4. every field without collection of Regions

What names gives to them ?

1. CountryNameWithCode
2. CountryWithoutUris
3. Country
4. CountryWithoutRegions ?

This is for a client in Britain. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my choices:

1. CountryId/CountryIdentity/CountryRef/CountryEntry
2. Country/CountryDetails/CountyAllInfo
3. CountryWithRegions
4. CountryWithUris

Answer (score 2):

Is this to name methods to return the Country object and reduce the amount of data trasferred?

What about: Country(bool includeRegions, bool includeURIs)

Comment: It look fine, but what If my class has for example 10 fields ? It wouldn't look fine